# How to ignore events in LabView triggered outside of a particular sequence frame?

Tags: events, event-handling, workflow, labview

Using event structures in LabView can get confusing, especially when mixing them with a mostly synchronous workflow. My question is, when an event structure exists in one frame of a sequence, how can I force it to ignore events (e.g. mousedown on a particular button) that were triggered while the workflow is in another frame of the sequence?

Currently, the event structures only process the events at the correct frame in the sequence, but if one was triggered while the workflow is in the previous frame, it processes those too and I want it to ignore any events that weren't triggered in the frame that the event structure exists within.

http://puu.sh/hwnoO/acdd4c011d.png

Here's part of my workflow. If the mousedown is triggered while the left part is executing, I want the event structure to ignore those events once the sequence reaches it.

Comment: I live in a small world and have never used event structures that way.  Would you mind describing what it is your are trying to do?  Not the implementation, but the functionality you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm generating a random sequence of button flashes, during which the user is not allowed to click the buttons. Then in the next frame the user is to repeat the pattern of button flashes in the same order by clicking on them. My goal was to prevent cheating by allowing the button clicks to fill the event queue while the buttons were flashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of placing the event structure inside your main program sequence, put it in a separate loop and have it pass the details of each event to the main sequence by means of a queue. Then you can discard the details of the events you don't want by flushing the queue at the appropriate point.

Alternatively you could use a boolean control to determine whether the event loop sends event details to the queue or discards them, and toggle the boolean with a local variable from the main sequence.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. Just to clarify, by queue, you just mean an array, right?

Comment: No, I mean a queue - search the LabVIEW help if you haven't learned about these yet. You can create a queue for any data type you like but for your application you might want to send an integer value corresponding to which button was clicked, or maybe a cluster of that integer and a timestamp so your main loop knows when the click took place. Have a look at some of the queue examples for more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can register for events dynamically. Registration is the point in time at which the event structure starts enqueueing events, and in your case this happens when the VI the event structure is in enters run mode (meaning it's executing or one of its callers is). You can change it so that you register using the Register for Events node and then you would only get events from that point on. When you unregister you will stop getting events.

There's a very good presentation by Jack Dunaway going into some details about events [here](ftp://LabVIEW_Videos:LabVIEW@frc.tecnova.com/2013%20NIWeek/Presentations_avi/Jack%20Dunaway_User%20Events%20Tips%20and%20Tricks.avi).

You can find the code for it [here](https://github.com/wirebirdlabs/LabVIEW-User-Events-Tips-Tricks-and-Sundry/archive/master.zip).

In LabVIEW 2013 and later there are additional options for controlling the events queue, but I won't go into them here.

Answer (score 0):

http://puu.sh/hwsBE/fe50dee671.png

I couldn't figure out how to flush the event queue for built-in event types like mousedown, but I managed to get around that by creating a static reference to the VI and setting the cursor to busy during the previous sequence, disabling clicking. Then when the sequence for the event structure is reached, I unset the cursor from busy, which re-enables clicking.